# Laravel Eloquent ->take(5) not working if got less results

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

currently working on website where i need to make a list but on the homepage i want to show smaller version of the list with a maximum of 5 items so normally this would work.

```
$items = collect(DB::select('EXEC [List] ?',[
                Carbon::now()->year
            ])->take(5));
```

But now since its new website it hasn't got more than 5 records, and every new year the records retrieved will also be less than 5. tried using limit(5) as well but this also doesn't seem to be working  So does one of you have a solution for this?

if someting not fully clear just ask ill try to explain it better.

Comment: what the output of  limit(5)

Comment: the error is get Call to a member function limit() on array the same for take()

Comment: Does it work if you supply take() with a value you could deliver?

Comment: yes so far there is 1 record in it if i set take(1) it does work but as soon as i go take(2) or higher it fails

Comment: What are you doing with $items afterwards. Could you share the rest of your code?

Comment: wait never mind take(1) also not working could have sworn i tried that before but apparently not

Comment: How is your table built? How are you storing the date? How does the according model look like?

Comment: welll shit just found the answer. the query i used was collect(DB::select()->take()) but instead it should have been collect(DB::select())->take() sometimes i really hate those small things like this always overlook them. still thanks for trying to help.

Comment: You can add this as an answer with the explanation of `collect` and `take` methods.

Comment: Since you are calling a procedure, isn't it easier to add a 2nd parameter to it to limit results? If you do the thing you are currently doing then all results will be loaded in memory and then everything except 5 will be thrown away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using this function on an array. Try to do it in 2 steps.
First: get the collection.
Second: work with it.

```
//$items = collect(...) 
$items = $items->take(5);
```

**edit**
You ARE using it on that array. The inner paranthese closes your DB::select() call! 
try:

```
 $items = collect(DB::select('EXEC [List] ?', [Carbon::now()->year]))
   ->take(5);
```

**edit 2:**
As apokryfos already mentioned, this call gets more and more expensive as the database grows. When you only need those 5 entries you could try something like that:

```
$items = DB::table('TABLENAME')
    ->select('*')
    //assuming you have a created_at col which can be handled as date.
    ->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))   
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

This should prepare a less expensive database call as you don't select all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out
`$item = collect(DB::table('item')->select('*')->take(5)->get());`
may be you forgot to add `->get()` in query.

Answer (score 0):

well just found the answer. the query i used was

```
collect(DB::select()->take());
```

but instead it should have been

```
collect(DB::select())->take();
```

sometimes i really hate those small things like this always overlook them.